# How to take single input in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to take input by using code `int rs=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);` but it throw exception `ArrayOutOfBondException`. Please help me code is below.I need to take input only one time in commandline argument

```
package techgig;
import java.util.*;

public class Techgig {


 public static int ta[]={1,12,5,111,200,1000,10,9,6,7,4};


public static void main(String[] args) {
  Vector v = new Vector();    
    // TODO code application logic here
    System.out.println("Amount Mark has:");
    System.out.println("=============================");//here is the code
    int rs=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
   // int rs=50;
    System.out.print("===============================");
  //int a=0;
    int count=0;
    int min=0,temp,totalamount=0;
  System.out.print("\nToys Available:{");

 for(int a=0;a<ta.length;a++)
 {
     if(a!=0)
     {
         System.out.print(",");
     }
     System.out.print(ta[a]);

 }
 System.out.print("}\n");
 System.out.println("Buy Maximum toys with maximum left");

  for(int i=0;i<ta.length;i++)
  {

  // System.out.print("\t"+ ta[i]);
       for( int j=i+1;j<ta.length;j++)
      {
          if(ta[j]<ta[i])
          {
              temp=ta[j];
              ta[j]=ta[i];
              ta[i]=temp;
          }
         // System.out.print("\t"+ ta[i]);
      }

  }

  for(int k=0;k<ta.length;k++)
  {

      totalamount=min;
     // System.out.print("\t"+ ta[k]);
      min=min+ta[k];
      if(min >rs)
      {
          break;

      }
      count=count+1;
      v.add(ta[k]);
  }

  int sav=0;
  sav=rs-totalamount;
  //System.out.println("Amount Mark has:"+rs);
  System.out.println("Output:{"+v.size()+","+sav+"}");
  System.out.println("Explanation");      
  System.out.println("Maximum number of toys="+v.size()+""+v);
  System.out.println("Saving="+sav);
}
}
```

Comment: How do you run your program? Do you pass an argument to it? If not, why would there be an args[0]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass command line arguments while running java program.

If you don't pass any command line arguments then `args` will be empty array, that is with length `0`. And accessing `0`th element from empty array will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

Let the name of the class having your main method is `MyClass.java`  Then you must run your program from command line like

```
java MyClass 12
```

Where 12 is the command line argument which you are passing to your program(you may try with different argument)

---

[image]

**Note:** When you will not pass any argument but access the args in your program then you will see this exception originating

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `args[0]` you need to pass command line arguments to the program. If you're running your program from an IDE, you will get the  exception that you get.